# Singularity/docker: bash script does not parse arguments

Tags: bash, docker, singularity-container

I have this [tool](https://github.com/Louis-MG/Metadbgwas) that I want to use through singularity to process sequencing data. The main script is written in `bash`. I successfully changed `/bin/sh`to `/bin/bash` through an `ENTRYPOINT` but my arguments aren't parsed. Even not giving arguments is ignoring the `Help` function display.
My Dockerfile is :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
USER root
COPY ./install_docker.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./install_docker.sh && sh ./install_docker.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/Metadbgwas/metadbgwas.sh"]
ENV PATH="/Metadbgwas/:${PATH}"
ENV OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null
```

The `instal_docker.sh` :

```
apt-get update
apt install -y libgatbcore-dev libhdf5-dev libboost-all-dev libpstreams-dev zlib1g-dev g++ cmake git r-base-core
Rscript -e "install.packages(c('ape', 'phangorn'))"
Rscript -e "install.packages('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgearle/bugwas/master/build/bugwas_1.0.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')"
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Louis-MG/Metadbgwas.git
cd Metadbgwas
chmod +x metadbgwas.sh
chmod +x ./tools/phantomjs/phantomjs
chmod +x ./tools/gemma/gemma.0.93b
sed -i "51i#include <limits>" ./REINDEER/blight/robin_hood.h #temporary fix for REINDEER compilation
```

The last line fixes a bug for phantomjs.
You can test the singularity with the following command :
`singularity pull docker://007ptar007/metadbgwas:latest`

An exemple of how the tool would be used outside of the singularity:

```
bash metadbgwas.sh --files ./input --output ./output --K 17 6000000 --strains ./strains
```

I should see:
`Starting Lighter ...`
and the output of the tool Lighter, included in mine, and then the rest of the processing.

Comment: Can you give an example invocation that shows how you pass arguments?  What is in the entrypoint script; how would you know whether arguments are being handled correctly?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added the information. I know parameters are handled corectly because the pipeline starts and shows outputs adbout every file being processed by the first tool, then the second etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that removing the line `USER root` solved my problem. Using the `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]` was not necessary after the modification. The `Dockerfile` has the final form:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

COPY ./install_docker.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./install_docker.sh && sh ./install_docker.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/Metadbgwas/metadbgwas.sh"]
ENV PATH="/Metadbgwas/:${PATH}"
ENV OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/null
```

I have no idea why, but this is for another thread.